# Error 8600010F while trying to sync primary ID mail

Tags: 8.1, email, error

I am using a Nokia Lumia 635 with Windows phone 8.1 (non-cyan) version.  I don't have the app corner feature yet.

I have been unable to receive email from my phone but am able to send email.  The exact message I get is:

> We're having a problem syncing col401-m-hotmail.com at the moment.  Wait a little while, then try again.
>
> Error code: 8600010F

Without resetting my phone is there anything I can do to get the error to go away?

Thanks

Comment: Ended up resetting the phone.  With the phone backup feature, I was able to retrieve everything from only three days prior.  The problem ended up being a calendar sync issue.

Comment: Bro just follow this procedure for Lumia windows phones.
Setting > Phone update > check for update, it will automatically check for sync error and update. (Provided Data connection should be ON) By Vivek, Bangalore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up resetting the phone. With the phone backup feature, I was able to retrieve everything from only three days prior. The problem ended up being a calendar sync issue

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the email account and reinstate. Only took 2 mins so not as drastic as it sounds.